# Get Not supported for DML operations Exceptiom

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have an Update query with @Modifying annotation, but still get "org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations" Exception. Why is that?

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Candidates c SET c.party_id=null WHERE c.party_id=:party_id")
@Transactional
public List<Candidates> updateByPartyId(@Param("party_id") Integer party_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by changing the return type of the method to "void".

Comment: After a few hours of searching I finally found the reason, thank you very much. Сopy-paste is evil.